# php max execution time never ends

Tags: php, execution-time

I was dealing with a long-polling ajax script untill I realize the execution time of my php script NEVER ends.
I did the following:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(11);
ini_set('max_execution_time',11);
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');

$i=0;
while (true) {
    $i++;
    echo "<br>".$i;
    sleep(1);
}
echo "END";
?>
```

I get the first line as I expected; "11".
But the script is still counting... I keep the page echoing... I don't know when it will finish
Any suggestion? I dont have access to the server, it is at ehost.com

Comment: first is 11, after that 1 ...... 12, after that Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 11 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\php7\timeneverstop.php on line 7 What do you want?

Comment: The script keeps counting... right know is echoing more than 800... so...

Comment: It looks like it is OS-dependent - i.e., under Linux sleep() time is ignored so max_execution_time refers to real running time, not including sleeping time. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit

Comment: An sleep inside a While loop is a bad practice. But what is the code objective?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

> **Warning**
>   This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

Maybe that is your issue. Anyway also from the [safe mode's docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php):

> **Warning**
>   This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: That was the first I though, but in [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) says that "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0" and my version is 5.6.29

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094839/php-set-time-limit-does-not-work-safemode-is-off) might help you too.

Comment: Also [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493023/why-doesnt-set-time-limit-work-as-expected), especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493056/7431119)

Comment: for sure that should be the problem.... the sleep function doesn't count... finally it finish in 2753. thanks!